# Cual es la función de esta sentencia?

Tags: sql

En un procedimiento almacenado de mysql me encontré con este where que no se cual es su función específicamente.

```
WHERE 1=1
```

Comment: por sí mismo no hace nada, para lo único que sirve es cuando alguna app lo usa para agregar condiciones dinámicante; así siempre debe agregar simplemente `AND "Alguna Condición"`, en vez de revisar si debe poner `AND` o no. Se entiende?

Comment: un poco...podrias explicarlo mejor? y... como seria agregar condiciones dinámicante?

Comment: Supón que tienes una página web que te está mostrando una tabla con resultados y tienes la posibilidad de agregar filtros (por ejemplo, la fecha, color, etc). Entonces agregas el primer filtro y el sitio manda un `AND Fecha = '20170823'`, te fijas como no tiene que verificar si ya había una condición en el `WHERE`?. Sin el `WHERE 1=1`, la página web tendría que haber revisado "existe algún filtro? -> si no, poner `WHERE fecha = '20170823'`, si ya existe, poner `AND Fecha = '20170823'`

Comment: Agrego un uso más, cuando hay que hacer un "debug" de las distintas condiciones de un `WHERE` si la primer condición es `1=1` y las siguientes se escriben en cada línea arrancando con un `AND` o un `OR` podemos ir comentando todas las clausulas sin romper la consulta.

Answer (score 4):

Esa expresion siempre retornará verdadero, por lo tanto equivale a no tener la expresion, tal vez durante el proceso de desarrollo quien lo hizo estuvo experimentando con posibles filtros y al final decidió que dejaría el procedimiento almacenado sin filtro.

Otra posibilidad es que el desarrollador piense implementar un where dinamico, en este caso, esta expresion se usa para evitar la excepcion de la primera expresion de filtro, asi poder tratar las siguientes partes del Where de la misma forma agregandole siempre un AND al principio, si no se usara 1=1, el AND del pricipio fallaria por que la expresion quedaría :

```
Where and Campo='valor'
```

con 1=1 quedaria

```
Where 1=1 and Campo='Valor'
```

Lo cual es correcto.

Answer (score 0):

**`WHERE`**

Es parte de una sentencia SQL que especifica una condición que debe cumplirse para que los datos sean devueltos sentencia SQL.

Estas sentencias SQL pueden ser de selección de registros como `SELECT` o de modificación como `UPDATE` y de eliminación como `DELETE`.

```
--Esta sentencia selecciona los vehiculos cuyo
--modelo sea igual a 2017
SELECT matricula, marca, modelo, color 
FROM tablaAutos
WHERE modelo=2017

--Esta sentencia selecciona los vehiculos cuyo
--modelo sea igual a 2017
SELECT matricula, marca, modelo, color 
FROM tablaAutos
WHERE modelo=2017

--Esta senetencia borra los registros cuya
--condicion sea que el modelo sea igual a 2001
DELETE FROM tablaAutos WHERE modelo=2001
```

En [esta página](https://desarrolloweb.com/manuales/tutorial-sql.html) hay un buen tutorial.

Comment: Los fragmentos de código o Snippets solo funcionan para Javascript, HTML y CSS. Cualquier otro lenguaje no está contemplado.

Answer (score 0):

Pues a menudo tiene sentido en consultas que se generan de forma dinámica. Es una buena forma fácil de poder ir añadiendo condiciones dinámicamente a un `WHERE` sin obtener errores (sólo añadiendo `AND condicion` al final):

```
SELECT * FROM Tabla1 WHERE 1=1
SELECT * FROM Tabla1 WHERE 1=1 AND Condicion1 
SELECT * FROM Tabla1 WHERE 1=1 AND Condicion1 AND Condicion2
...
```

También está relacionado con los intentos de evitar inyeccción de SQL en las sentencias.

De todas formas, siendo un procedimiento almacenado, a ninguna de ellas le veo mucho sentido.